# Defining base class member pointer with the adress of derived class member

Tags: c++, class, pointers

See example of what I'm talking about in the code below, in class B.
Am I doing something wrong, memory wise ?

I'm having segmentation faults that I didn't have before that...

```
class Obj
{
};

class ObjDerived : public Obj
{
};

template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    Obj<T> *pObj;

    public:
    A(Obj<T>* pO) : pObj(pO) {}
    void doSomethingWithObj()
    { pObj->print(); }

};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    public:
    B() : A<T>(&o), o(ObjDerived<T>(1.0)) {}

    void doSmthg()
    { (this->pObj)->print(); }

    public:
        ObjDerived<T> o;

};
```

Comment: This is obviously not your real code, since the first two classes are not templates but used as such. The code you showed (apart from the missing templates) is OK, please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I agree. The code shown is okay. But it's easy to make slight changes to it that will cause problems because `o` hasn't yet been constructed when a pointer to it as passed to `A::A`.

Comment: Also, just to mention it, `A::doSomethingWithObj()` and `B::doSmthg` do exactly the same thing (calling the `print()` function of `A`'s member variable). As `A` is being publicly inherited, that makes `B::doSmthg` redundant.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sure it's easy to make slight changes, but I don't like guessing. OP should take the time to create a SSCCE, which often already solves the problem without even having to ask someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to make `print()` a virtual function in class `Obj` and override it in class `ObjDerived`. Then you don't need to mess around with raw pointers which are evil.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue that would occur with your code is that in the constructor for `B` you're passing a variable that you've not yet created to the base class.

```
B()
    : A<T>( &o)
    , o( ObjDerived<T>( 1.0f))
{}
```

In the constructor, the commands are performed in order so you're passing `B::o` which hasn't been created yet to `A::A` and THEN creating the `B::o` variable.

The only solution that comes to mind, if you really want to stick to this class structure would be to make `A::pObj` a pointer to a pointer so it could then access the new variable by first going to `B::o`. However that would look horrendously messy in my opinion.

EDIT: As John Smith has said, I think you need to look into using virtual functions and inheritance a bit more to neaten the class structure out.